# Перевод в тексте причины закрытия

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Надо чтобы когда был 1 участник закрытия, то писалось не "участниками", а "участником"
2. Нужен перевод текста в скобках

Предлагаю свои варианты перевода:

> Список голосовавших за закрытие доступен для просмотра только пользователям с привилегиями закрытия/переоткрытия

> Список голосовавших за закрытие доступен только пользователям с привилегиями закрытия/переоткрытия

> Список голосовавших за закрытие виден только пользователям с привилегиями закрытия/переоткрытия

Comment: Один момент  - правильно писать с привИлегиями. Сейчас в плашке закрытия ваш  третий вариант с этим недочётом.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо, исправил у себя в вопросе. Думаю вам лучше открыть новый вопрос с этой ошибкой, чтобы его приняли

Comment: Это вопрос сейчас поднялся вверх, может, заметят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Не репутации ради, а порядка для..."*
> Данный ответ дан, чтобы можно было отфильтровать вопросы по локализации, не имеющие переводов.
>  Голосовать за него не нужно, а вот принять ответ или закрыть - желательно.

**Данное сообщение переведено:**

> (List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege)
> (Список голосовавших за закрытие виден только пользователям с привелегиями закрытия/переоткрытия)

**Ссылка на перевод:** https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17875

В интерфейсе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]