# Неправильная форма существительно в плашке закрытого вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, золотые-знаки, множественное-число

Неправильное число - "участниками", хотя перечислен всего один участник.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вдруг, число правильное (¬‿¬)

Comment: @Grundy ой... ⊙▂⊙

Comment: Возможный [дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12061/176217)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущей реализации есть только одна строка без разделения на кол-во участников, осуществивших закрытие.

Поэтому я сделал запрос на MSE [Plural forms are needed for close notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387649/339911) для добавления разных форм в зависимости от кол-ва участников.

Когда (и если) его выполнят, можно будет сделать разные переводы и закрыть проблему.